# yup validation with multiple fields

Tags: yup, react-hook-form

I wanna validate fields with yup and react-hook-form. I wanna make sure at least one of the 2 fields will contain some value. For some reason the `urls` and `instructions` are undefined (see where it's printed) in the validation. Any ideas why this is happening?

When I submit the form values come in as:

```
{ meta,urls: Array(1), meta,instructions: "" }
```

Validation code:

```
const schema = yup.object({
  processingType: yup.string(),
  meta: yup.object().shape({
    instructions: yup.string()
      .when('urls', {
        is: urls => {
          console.log('HERE', urls)
          return urls[0]?.url === ''
        },
        then: yup.string().required().min(1),
        otherwise: yup.string()
      }),
    urls: yup.array().of(yup.object().shape({ url: yup.string() }))
      .when('instructions', {
        is: instructions => {
          console.log('THERE', instructions);
          return instructions === ''
        },
        then: yup.array().of(yup.object().shape({ url: yup.string() })).required().min(1),
        otherwise: yup.object().shape({ url: yup.string() })
      }),
  }, ['instructions', 'urls'])
});

const defaultValues = {
  processingType: '',
  meta: {
    instructions: '',
    urls: [{ url: '' }],
  }
};
```